# How to write python-django queires and import them?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongodb-query, django-mongodb-engine

**Data :**

```
{
  "Fruit": "Pomegranate",
  "District": "Nasik",
  "Taluka": "Nasik",
  "Revenue circle": "Nasik",
  "Sum Insured": 28000,
  "Area": 1200,
  "Farmer": 183
}

{
  "Fruit": "Pomegranate",
  "District": "Jalna",
  "Taluka": "Jalna",
  "Revenue circle": "Jalna",
  "Sum Insured": 28000,
  "Area": 120,
  "Farmer": 13
}

{
  "Fruit": "Guava",
  "District": "Pune",
  "Taluka": "Haveli",
  "Revenue circle": "Uralikanchan",
  "Sum Insured": 50000,
  "Area": 10,
  "Farmer": 100
}

{
  "Fruit": "Guava",
  "District": "Nasik",
  "Taluka": "Girnare",
  "Revenue circle": "Girnare",
  "Sum Insured": 50000,
  "Area": 75,
  "Farmer": 90
}

{
  "Fruit": "Banana",
  "District": "Nanded",
  "Taluka": "Nandurbar",
  "Revenue circle": "NandedBK",
  "Sum Insured": 5000,
  "Area": 2260,
  "Farmer": 342
}

{
  "Fruit": "Banana",
  "District": "Jalgaon",
  "Taluka": "Bhadgaon",
  "Revenue circle": "Bhadgaon",
  "Sum Insured": 5000,
  "Area": 220,
  "Farmer": 265
}
```

I want to write all types of combination queries, if someone wants information only for Fruit which is Guava then the output will be exact data for Guava only.

also if someone wants information only for Fruit which is Banana & Guava then the output will be exact data for Banana and Guava.

If fruit is equal to Banana

output will be data for Banana

If fruit is equal to Guava

output will be data for Guava

If fruit is equal to Banana and Guava

output will be data for Banana and Guava

Also, if someone wants information only for District which is Nasik then the output will be exact data for Nasik district only. Query for "District"

If District is equal to Nasik

output will be data for Nasik District

If District is equal to Nanded

output will be data for Nanded District

likewise, there is query for "Revenue_circle, Farmer etc.

I know how to write this queries in mongoshell using find

db.Wbcis.find({"Fruit":"Banana"})

db.Wbcis.find({"District":"Nasik"}) etc...

but I want to writing the queries  in the python script so I am confuse in models.py and views.py file.

I tired and type query  using Q objects in  models.py

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db import models

from django.db.models import Q

class Wbcis(models.Model):  
  Fruit = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
  District = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
  Taluka = models.CharField(max_length=50)    
  Revenue_circle = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
  Sum_Insured = models.FloatField()   
  Area = models.FloatField()
  Farmer = models.IntegerField()


def __str__(self):

    return self.Fruit

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:

  verbose_name_plural = 'wbcis'

from models import Wbcis
Guava =Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava'))
print Guava
Banana= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Banana'))
print Banana  
Pomegranate= Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Pomegranate'))   
print Pomegranate
Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava')&Q(Fruit='Banana'))   
print Guava_Banana
```

But, I know this is not correct way for query.
I need to write this in for loop or while loop.
can you please help me for how to writing this query using for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but your queries seem correct.

I think what you mean with your `for` loop, is that you can iterate over a query (technically, a `QuerySet`) to get the results.

For example:

```
Guava = Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava'))
for guava_entry in Guava:
    # Do something with the returned element here:
    print guava_entry
```

If you want to filter by multiple things, you can just have multiple conditions in your filter. For example, to get Bananas in Nanded

```
Guava = Wbcis.objects.filter(Fruit="Banana", District="Nanded")
```

You don't need to use a `for` loop for that. By default, `filter` combines your conditions using `and`. That means that in the example above, Fruit must be "Banana", **and** District must be "Nanded".

Looking at the examples you have in your question, you have this query:

```
Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava')&Q(Fruit='Banana'))
```

This query will never return any results. It is asking for an object that has both a Fruit of "Guava" **and** a Fruit of "Banana". What you want instead is this:

```
Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava') | Q(Fruit='Banana'))
```

This new query returns objects where fruit is either "Guava" or "Banana".

I understand this can be confusing, because you want to return Guavas **and** Bananas, but think of it as a boolean expression.

You can wrap this in a function like this:

```
def get_wbcis(fruit=None, district=None, talkua=None, min_farmer=None, max_farmer=None, limit=100):
    query = Wbcis.objects.all()
    if fuit is not None:
        query = query.filter(Fruit=fruit)

    if district is not None:
        query = query.filter(District=district)

    if taluka is not None:
        query = query.filter(Taluka=taluka)

    if min_farmer is not None:
        query = query.filter(Farmer__gte=min_farmer)

    if max_farmer is not None:
        query = query.filter(Farmer__lt=max_farmer)

    return query[:limit]
```

The `limit` parameter ensures that at most that many results are returned.

min_farmer in this example uses the `__gte` query operator, meaning that results with a Farmer greather than or equal to `min_farmer` will be returned.

max_farmer uses the __lt operator, so results with a farmer lower than, but not equal to `max_farmer`  will be returned.

Similarly, you could use __gt or __lte if you want different different inequality filters.

Your `views.py` could do something like this:

```
import json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from django.http import JsonResponse
from models import get_wbcis

def wbcis_view(request):
    fruit = request.GET.get("fruit")
    district = request.GET.get("district")
    taluka = request.GET.get("taluka")
    min_farmer = request.GET.get("min_farmer")
    max_farmer = request.GET.get("max_farmer")

    wbcis = get_wbcis(fruit, district, taluka, min_farmer, max_ffarmer)

    #convert them to JSON:
    dicts = []
    for wbci in wbcis:
        dicts.append(model_to_dict(wbci))

    return JsonResponse(dicts)
```

Comment: yes I want to iterate over a query. suppose we want data output for  some fruit in some taluka  then  how to write query?

Comment: so, we need to write all queries in this form?  for District=Pune for District=Nasik....so on ? or  using for loop we can do this?

Comment: Do you mean you'd want to group fruits by district? So for example, get all the fruits in Pune, and then all the fruits in Nasik and so on?

Comment: yes . exactly...  suppose I want data for  banana fruit in  nanded district, then  output gives me answer.  or if someone want data for Guava fruit in nasik  district then output gives me answer

Comment: yes this is helpful,  so, I need to write all types of query in models.py file  for call it this query i need to write in views.py file? if someone want information for "pune"district -select  taluka --"uralikanchan" and select fruit --banana , then  output will gives exact this  http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/?District=Pune&?Taluka=uralikanchan&Fruit=Banana

Comment: yes ...  fruit is either "Guava" or "Banana". Guava_Banana=Wbcis.objects.filter(Q(Fruit='Guava') | Q(Fruit='Banana'))  this is I want..

Comment: You can wrap your query in a function, which you can call from your view. See my updated answer for info.

Comment: Okay, so  this function I need to write in views.py file? if someone use "Taluka" instead of "district" to find  fruits. then what we have to do?  for example : in  taluka : "Haveli" how many fruits are made? so we need to use  Taluka instead of  District in wrap function?

Comment: You can put this function anywhere you want, but I'd put it in `models.py`, and then your view can call it. To add more search criteria, you can just add parameters to your function.

Comment: Oh okay sir , so we can add more parameters  likewise def get_wbcis(fruit=None, district=None, taluka=None, farmer=None):    if someone want information for  district =Pune , revenue_circle=Uralikanchan for farmer there are more than 100 then match this 3 parameters  criteria and show exact answer,  there I am confuse. how to write this types of query,

Comment: I just updated my answer with more function parameters, so yes, you can extend this to farmer, revenue_circle, etc. I'm not sure what you mean with the "if there are more than 100 then match this 3 parameters criteria. In the current version, it'll just match every parameter you pass in, and give you the exact result. If you want to limit the number of results that are returned, you can put [:100] after your query. (updating my answer...)

Comment: for example: we want to show data output where farmer is less than 100 in our data . So, we can get data output 2  out of 6.  like Q(farmer_lt=100)   show only 2 output which is strictly less than 100 farmers.  but there some specific criteria that is in District=> Nasik, how many data gives farmers are less than 100 to made fruit ==> Guava.

Comment: You can use Farmer__lt=100 to filter farmers below 100. I updated my answer. With this, you could say 127.0.0.1/api/?district=Nasik&fruit=Guava&max_farmer=100 to get the example you gave.

Comment: thank you very much. it's really helpful for me..!! :)

Comment: If we  want to filter by multiple things,  For example, Areas to get Bananas in Nanded 

Guava = Wbcis.objects.filter(Area_lt=100,Fruit="Banana", District="Nanded") is this correct?